# Series data binding in LightningChart

Tags: wpf, data-binding, charts

I see there's 3 WPF APIs available in [LightningChart](http://arction.com/). Bindable/semi-bindable and non-bindable. What's exactly difference of them?

How to bind a collection of data points to make a line chart?

Answer (score 4):

- **Bindable chart API**: DependencyProperties, ObservableCollection-based lists and data inputs. Bind everything. Configure in XAML. Good performance when compared to competitors but not as good as semi-bindable or non-bindable. The performance difference shows especially when using hundreds of series and millions of data points.

  - **Semi-bindable chart API**: DependencyProperties, ObservableCollections in  lists. Data input is array-based and must be done in code-behind. So you can bind UI settings and chart objects, but just feed the data in code. Very good performance.
  - **Non-bindable chart API**: No DependencyProperties, no ObservableCollections in any lists or data inputs. Regular properties and usage in code-behind. Best performance and multithreading features. Over billion points can be monitored in real-time monitoring as our [demo application](http://arction.com/billion_data_points_visualization) shows.

With Bindable chart API you can configure chart and bind like this

```
<Window x:Class="BindingExamplePointLineSeries.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:lcub="http://schemas.arction.com/bindablecharting/ultimate/"
    x:Name="thisTest"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <lcub:LightningChartUltimate>
        <lcub:LightningChartUltimate.ViewXY>
            <lcub:ViewXY>
                <lcub:ViewXY.YAxes>
                    <lcub:AxisY/>
                </lcub:ViewXY.YAxes>
                <lcub:ViewXY.XAxes>
                    <lcub:AxisX/>
                </lcub:ViewXY.XAxes>
                <lcub:ViewXY.PointLineSeries>
                    <lcub:PointLineSeries Points="{Binding ElementName=thisTest, Path = Points}" PointsVisible="True"/>
                </lcub:ViewXY.PointLineSeries>
            </lcub:ViewXY>
        </lcub:LightningChartUltimate.ViewXY>
    </lcub:LightningChartUltimate>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Random rand = new Random();
        SeriesPointCollection points0 = new SeriesPointCollection();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            SeriesPoint p = new SeriesPoint();
            p.X = i;
            p.Y = rand.NextDouble() * 10.0;
            points0.Add(p);
        }
        Points = points0;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PointsProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register(
          "Points",
          typeof(SeriesPointCollection),
          typeof(MainWindow)
      );

    public SeriesPointCollection Points
    {
        get { return GetValue(PointsProperty) as SeriesPointCollection; }
        set { SetValue(PointsProperty, value as Object); }
    }
}
```

and then you get the chart with your data bound: 
[image: WPF data binding chart]

Comment: Good explanation of differences. I just noticed there's standalone binding projects in your suite, I'll start going through them. Thanks for this simple example.